# Import multiple csv, perform function, export csv in R

Tags: r, loops, csv

I have a code written for a single csv import(PO1_CMJ_T01.csv), function performed, then an output csv to the setwd. I would like this function to loop so I can import n files, the function to analyse the data, then export n files to setwd folder

I have tried lapply to create a loop for the files but I cannot get this to work. I am stuck with getting the loop to start and analyze file by file. Any help would be absolutely amazing. Thanks in advance SO!

```
# load required packages
require(readr)
library(tidyverse)
getwd()


# import data frame
filename <- "P01_CMJ_T01.csv"
datapath <- ''
Jump.1 = read_csv(
  paste0(datapath, filename),
  col_names = TRUE,
  skip = 3,
  trim_ws = TRUE
)
```

Perform functions  etc

```
# Write output
output <- data.frame(
     ),
  cell = NA
)


show(output)


write.csv(output,
          file = paste0('output-', sub('.xlsx', '.csv', filename)))

If I import 50 files, I would like the analysis to take place, then
```

write.csv to output 50 files to the wd folder

Comment: Please work on reducing your problem into a *minimal* working example: the vast majority of code there doesn't pertain to your question, so it is both distracting and slowing down anybody showing interest in your question. For me, in general, I try to avoid a scrolling code block; much more and it indicates I might have too much (there are always exceptions). Code that does things like calculate the mean and/or `mutate` one column from another is (if I understand your need correctly) completely moot and unnecessary.

Comment: Will do, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I would write a function that takes a single file and does the three steps of read, analyze, and write. (If the analysis step is long, a separate function may help.) Then, you can loop across the 50 files using your function and either `lapply` or a `for` loop or something similar.

Here is an example:

```
files1 <- list.files(
    file.path(system.file(package = "readr"), "extdata"), 
    pattern = "csv$", full.names = TRUE)

f1 <- function(file) {
    # read
    df1 <- suppressMessages(readr::read_csv(file, guess_max = 1050))
    # analyze
    df2 <- f2(df1)
    # write
    tmp1 <- file.path(dirname(file), paste0("new_", basename(file)))
    readr::write_csv(df2, path = tmp1)
    invisible(tmp1) # optional
}

f2 <- function(data) {
    df2 <- head(data)
    message("Results has ", nrow(df2), " rows and ", ncol(df2), " columns.")
    return(df2)
}

lapply(files1, f1)
```